# Linking webrtc with Qt on Windows

Tags: qt, webrtc, linker-errors

I'm trying to link libwebrtc library with Qt application on Windows platform.

I get a lot of  linking errors like this:

```
webrtc.lib(jitter_estimator.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in ....obj
```

Apparently this is because the libwebrtc is compiled with `-MT` (static runtime) buiflag, and Qt application is compiled with `-MD` flag.

Is it possible to make Qt application compile with -MT? Is it possible to make libwebrtc to compile with -MD ?

Answer (score 2):

Summary of my investigations:

a) It is possible to compile libwebrtc with -MD flags. This is not possible without modifying the sources, but the modification is trivial: 
change src/build/config/win/BUILD.gn: in the statement `config("default_crt")`
replace

```
#Desktop Windows: static CRT
configs = [":static_crt"]
```

to 
    configs = [":dynamic_crt"]

b) It is possible to recompile Qt from sources with -MT -MTd flags. 
To do this: edit `Src/qtbase/mkspecs/common/msvc-desktop.conf`, replace `-MD` `-MDd` in this file with `-MT` `-MTd`.
configure with option -static.

Both solutions seems to work, at least produce compilable and linkable binaries.